# how to filter the table in search tab by selecting the drop down

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

> ```
> I've created an table dynamically where we can create an user list. and I stored the users's list in the array of objects called
> ```
>
> 'data'. Now I want to filter the users by typing in the search bar
> input and render the users by selecting the dropdown value which are
> the table column headings 'username, role, status'.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
 const [value, setValue] = useState('');

 const dropDownChange = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
 };

        const searchRows = (rows) => {
      if(value === 'username' ){               //I want to select the dropdown for particular 
      filter results
    return rows.filter((row) => row.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
         else if(value == value.includes('Role')){          // want to select the column name.   
      return rows.filter((row) => row.role.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
        }   else if(value == value.includes('status')){          // want to select the column name.   
         return rows.filter((row) => row.role.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
   }
    }
       }/// Above code is not working

       { searchRows(data)
        // .filter((item) => item.username.toLowerCase().includes(search))
        .map((user) => {
          return (
       ......mapping the users data......


       /

            /Drop down code...
               <select value={value} onChange={dropDownChange} name="filter" id="filter">
          <option value="username">Username</option>
          <option value="role">Role</option>
          <option value="status">Status</option>
        </select>

       // Search Bar Code....
    <input
      type="text"
      id="search"
      placeholder="Search users... "
      onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
```

I want to change the filter results according to the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve. If I understand correctly, you want to filter by role with `<select>` and filter by name with `<input type="text">`.

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const arrayOfObjs = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Tiffany', role: 'JS'},
      {id: 2, name: 'George', role: 'JS'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Tom', role: 'PHP'},
    ]
const Example = ({title}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(arrayOfObjs);
    const [dropDownFilter, setDropDownFilter] = useState('initial');
    const [searchfilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('initial');
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if(dropDownFilter === 'initial') return;
        if(dropDownFilter === ''){
          setData(arrayOfObjs);
          return;
        }
        setData(arrayOfObjs.filter(item => item.role === dropDownFilter))
    }, [dropDownFilter]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if(searchfilter === 'initial') return;
        if(searchfilter === ''){
          setData(arrayOfObjs.filter(item => item.role === dropDownFilter));
          return;
        }
        setData(arrayOfObjs.filter(item => item.role === dropDownFilter &&  item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfilter.toLowerCase())))
    }, [searchfilter]);
  
    return (
        <div>
           <select onChange={e => setDropDownFilter(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="">Select Filter</option>
              <option value="JS">Role JS</option>
              <option value="PHP">Role PHP</option>
           </select>
           
           <input onKeyUp={e => setSearchFilter(e.target.value)} type="text" />
           
           <div>
              {data.map(item => 
                <div key={item.id}>
                  {item.name} | Role: {item.role}
                </div>
              )}
           </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Test Snippet" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm already mapping and displaying the users in my UI. I have to make the changes without disturbing it. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try to copy my version to your environment to try if it's working? If not please try to copy this code and verify if it's working and we let's take from there.

Comment: Also I understand you want to make your code work without big changes. Anyone would help here but you posted only part of your code so we never will understand what is going on there.

Comment: I am already having the user list in state called 'data' and I am filtering using the state only. const searchRows = (rows) => {
        return rows.filter((row) => 
        row.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 
        row.role.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 
        row.status.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
        )
}
I am doing the global filter using this above code but I want to do it by selecting the drop down

Comment: Sorry @Santhosh, if you will be able to make sandbox like I did (or maybe https://codesandbox.io/), I'll be more than happy to help.